# Is there a MathJaX equivalent of `\makebox` or something similar?

Tags: discussion, formatting, mathjax

I apologize if this is the wrong forum, but I recently discovered `\makebox` and certain other formatting commands such as `\clap` and `\hss` are not available in MathJaX. Is it possible to load those commands on, say, math.stackexchange.com, or are there equivalents? Specifically, is there a way to declare a box of width `0` that is centered, with all of its content displayed anyway, in MathJaX?

Comment: @egreg, apparently `\rlap` and `\llap` are available; I've used them. But I continue to be frustrated concerning center overlap techniques.

Comment: You might try searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Comment: I have just a hunch that this is related to your [previous question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12686/1543) `:-)`

Comment: @WillieWong, you are very astute. Actually, I'm currently trying to create a workaround using the `\style` command, with not much success. If there is any way to do this in MathJaX without CSS, I would like to know about it.

Comment: `\hss` and its less insane counterpart `\hfill` would be nice for the end of proof marker.

Comment: Are you guys just going to comment, or does somebody know the answer?